# How can I load moment-timezone with data from 2012 2022 with webpack?

Tags: webpack, momentjs

Because I want to reduce the size of my bundle, I want to load moment timezone with data from 2012 2022.

Actually I do :

```
import moment from "moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022";
```

But randomly I got an error when I try to use moment-timezone:

```
moment.utc(...).tz(...) is undefined
```

Do you have an idea how I can load properly moment and/or moment-timezone to avoid moment.utc(...).tz(...) is undefined ?

I'm using webpack 3